# XPath return empty value from string xml

Tags: java, xml, string, xpath

I have a big xml:

```
<SomeRequest>
<Reservation>
...
</Reservation>
<Payment>
<cardNumber>....</cardNumber>
</Payment>
</SomeRequest>
```

and now I want to get `cardNumber` value from this xml. It is String, I cannot parse it into xml `Document` because it takes too much time.
So, I have this `string` and I use `XPath` on it like this:

```
String field = "/SomeRequest/Payment/cardNumber/text()";
XPathExpression compile = XPATH_FACTORY.newXPath().compile(field);
String value = compile.evaluate(new InputSource(new StringReader(request))); //request is xml string
```

but after do it, the `value` is empty. I tried to do it on xml `Document` (parse it) and then it worked. But now I want to do it on simple `String`.
I don't want to use regex on this string, because it can provide a lot of problems.
How can I get this `cardNumber` value using XPath?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right way, that works

```
public class XpathTest {
    private XPathFactory XPATH_FACTORY = new XPathFactoryImpl();

    private String request = "<SomeRequest>\n" +
            "<Reservation>\n" +
            "...\n" +
            "</Reservation>\n" +
            "<Payment>\n" +
            "<cardNumber>123</cardNumber>\n" +
            "</Payment>\n" +
            "</SomeRequest>";

    @Test
    public void name() throws Exception {
        String field = "/SomeRequest/Payment/cardNumber/text()";
        XPathExpression compile = XPATH_FACTORY.newXPath().compile(field);
        String value = compile.evaluate(new InputSource(new StringReader(request)));
        assertThat(value, equalTo("123"));
    }
}
```

Comment: @allocer Check the path, please. Is "SomeRequest" the root tag?

Comment: yes, it is. I have `String field = "/SomeRequest/Payment/cardNumber/text()";`

Comment: I may only suggest to check the path and source xml. Tag names are case sensitive. Play with the test until see the cause.

Comment: Ok, I will try. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `toString` on `Document`.